# Webpack: Exclude directory in ts-loader

Tags: typescript, webpack

For one of my projects I need to use a prisma schema that is stored in another repository. I have added this repository as submodule.

##Directory structure:

```
├── compose.yaml
├── second-repository
│   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   ├── nest-cli.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── prisma
│   │   └── schema.prisma
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── app.controller.spec.ts
│   │   ├── app.controller.ts
│   │   ├── app.module.ts
│   │   ├── app.service.ts
│   │   └── main.ts
│   ├── tsconfig.build.json
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── src
│   ├── index.ts
├── tsconfig.json
└── webpack-config.js
```

The submodule repository is located in "second-repository".

When I'm trying to build my project using webpack, webpack seems to include the source files from the other repository, even though my code doesn't use them. Because these files have different dependencies, my build fails with dependency-errors on the source files from the submodule.

```
ERROR in /home/user/Development/repository-one/second-repository/src/main.ts
1:28-42
[tsl] ERROR in /home/user/Development/repository-one/second-repository/src/main.ts(1,29)
      TS2307: Cannot find module '@nestjs/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

I don't want these src files being included, I only need the prisma schema from the submodule. Unfortunately I can't simply move the prisma-schema to a different repository.
How do I get webpack to simply ignore the src files from the submodule?

I have tried using module.noParse, module.rules.exclude & even defining the submodule as external, but these all have no effects on my problem. My current webpack-config:

```
const WebpackCopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || "development",
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  target: 'node',
  entry: {
    "index": "./src/index.ts",
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve("./dist"),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  module: {
    noParse: (content) => {console.log(content); return /second-repository/.test(content)}, 
    rules: [
      {
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /(node_modules)|(second-repository)/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"],
    modules: [
      "src",
      "node_modules"
    ]
  },
  externals: {
    puppeteer: "require('puppeteer')", // use additional double quotes here to define valid external

    "second-repository": "require('second-repository')",
  },
  plugins: [
    new WebpackCopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: "./node_modules/.prisma/client/schema.prisma", to: "schema.prisma" },
        { from: "./node_modules/.prisma/client/libquery_engine*", to: "./[name][ext]"},
      ],
    }),
  ]
};
```